# Mute sound in Android with a button

Tags: android

I'd like to mute an android device with a button, what are the basic ways of doing it? (Also I would like to mute it for only a user inputted period of time if possible.

```
MuteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View view) { 
float seconds = Float.parseFloat(inputSeconds.getText().toString());
long milsec = (long) (seconds * 1000); ; } });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple volume types in android. If you want to completely mute the device you have to mute all of those types.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) con.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, (int) volumeLevel, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI /*or 0 for not showing system notification*/)
```

This will set the system vollume type to the volumeLevel you want. Do the same for all other volume streams (music, notifications etc..).

If you want to set it back to normal after a few seconds just use a Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do whatever you want here 
        //after the delay is over
    }
}, milliseconds);
```

The tricky part here is that each stream type has a different max value. So before setting it back to bormal you must do this

```
int maxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
```

to get the max value for a specific stream type. And then set that value.

Comment: So for ex. Notification sound will be. STREAM_NOTIFICATION?

Comment: yes. you can see all the available streams in android official website. (or just use autocomplete in android studio)

Comment: since i can see you're new here...when an answer is satisfying you mark it as accepted so that others can see it

Comment: After I tested it I will surely do that, thank you for your help.

Comment: What shall i put instead of con.getSystemService ?
(cannot resolve symbol 'con')

Comment: IF the various equalizer functions are attached to the mediaPlayer, then there is always a short "blip" as a http audio stream is started, stemming from that stream. How to COMPLETELY have the volume set at zero. (I use the code above for getter and setter of stream volume).